# Using CMake to index source files of an external library with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, indexing, cmake

I am using CMake to build a project with external libraries by using "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles".

Importing in Eclipse leads to a working project, but only all header files and my implemented source files are recognized correctly by the index of Eclipse.
I would also like to navigate through the source files for one external library by using "ctrl+click". I don't know how to add the *.cpp files of that external library in my CMakeList.txt to get them recognized by the indexer without building the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mark the .cpp files as "header file only" like this:

```
# find all filenames in the lib path and gather them in $YOUR_LIB
FILE(GLOB YOUR_LIB path_to_library/*.?pp)

# create a seperate sourcegroup so it doesn't clutter up the rest of your code
SOURCE_GROUP(\\lib FILES ${YOUR_LIB})

# mark them as header-file only
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(${YOUR_LIB} PROPERTIES HEADER_FILE_ONLY TRUE)

# add both your code and the lib-code to the project
ADD_EXECUTABLE(program ${YOUR_CODE} ${YOUR_LIB})
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but the files get not indexed. If I remove the setting of the HEADER_FILE_ONLY option, he tries to build the files. That means that they are included in the build, but the Indexer is not finding them. Rebuilding the index leads to the same output as before: "Indexed 'g2o_ba@build' (5 sources, 811 headers) in 44.54 sec". I also checked the eclipse properties "Index source files not included in the build", "index unused headers".

Comment: After a long break I continued working on my cmake and eclipse problem. I figured out, that your solution is not working with the cmake "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" settings. But setting up the project with the Unix Makefile generator after this [tutorial](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake:Eclipse_UNIX_Tutorial) leads to the desired functionalty (using your cmake snippets). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to attach external library source files to the Eclipse project that is compatible with CMake project generator.

It turns out that to indexing and "ctrl+click" navigation works correctly only when external library sources are direct descendants of the project source folder. Therefore the solution is following:

- Scan external library folder for source files.
- Create a child folder under project's source folder.
- Symlink discovered sources inside the created folder.

I created a CMake function `attachExternalSources` that performs above steps:

```
function(attachExternalSources librarySourceLocation folderName)
    # Create folder for Geant4 sources
    file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${folderName})

    message(STATUS "Searching for C++ sources in \"${librarySourceLocation}\"...")
    FILE(GLOB_RECURSE libSources
        ${librarySourceLocation}/*.c
        ${librarySourceLocation}/*.cpp
        ${librarySourceLocation}/*.cxx
        ${librarySourceLocation}/*.cc
    )

    message(STATUS "Symlinking sources into\n   \"${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${folderName}\"\n   Please wait...")
    foreach(source ${libSources})
        # Obtain source filename
        get_filename_component(source_filename ${source} NAME)

        # Create symlink unless it already exists
        set(symlink "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${folderName}/${source_filename}")     
        if(NOT EXISTS ${symlink})
            execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E create_symlink ${source} ${symlink})
        endif()
    endforeach()
    
    # Scan all the symlinks created under the project folder and disable their compilation
    FILE(GLOB sources_symlinks ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${folderName}/*)
    SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(${sources_symlinks} PROPERTIES HEADER_FILE_ONLY TRUE)
endfunction()
```

The use of the function is following. Paste above function code in your `CMakeLists.txt`. Next, use it as follows:

```
attachExternalSources("path/to/external/library/sources" "library-sources")
```

First parameter is location of the external library source code. Second argument is the name of a folder inside your project that that will contain source symlinks.

P.S. I tested function with Eclipse 4.19 and CMake 3.20.5.